# Swap the rows of one matrix to make sure each matrices obtained is different to another?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix **NxM**.

**N** is big enough `N >> 10000`.

I wonder if there is an algorithm to mix all the lines of a matrix to get a 100 matrix for example. My matrices C must not be identical.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can use random module (random.random of Python) to get two integers between 1 to 10000, and then swap the two selected rows. Conditions : two randoms different one to the other, and a couple of random must be different to another couple selected before.  The thing is that it won't ensure your matrix is different to another (you can swap two different rows with the same content for example) : this is the main problem ! You can do it easily with the equals (!=) operator but in terms of performance it'll break your CPU.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / found aou so  far? Share **your** findings.

Comment: What do you mean by "mix all the lines"?  What are the "matrices C"?

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want to keep the shape of the matrix and just shuffle the rows or do you want to get subsets of the matrix?
For the first case I think the permutation algorithm from numpy could be your choice. Just create a permutation of a index list, like Souin propose.

For the second case just use the numpy choice funtion (also from the random module) without replacement if I understood your needs correctly.

Comment: Here is the function that I work with, in this fontion nothing guarantees that we will not have almost identical matrix I want completely different matrices (+ 50%) to the original matrix. thank you   //                                                                                       def shuffling( X):
    indx=np.arange(len(X))          # create a array with indexes for X data
    np.random.shuffle(indx)
    X=X[indx]
    return X